# How to solve this inequality for $x,y$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

How to solve
$(x^2+y^2-4)(x-y)\leq 0$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

How can i find the solution sets w/o drawing a graph?

Comment: Why do you want to do this without a graph?

Comment: Agreed : it makes no sense to refuse to draw a picture to solve such a "graphical" problem. **Even** if you justify it like Brian did below.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $(x^2+y^2-4)(x-y)=0$ if $x=y$ or $x^2+y^2=4$, i.e., if the point $\langle x,y\rangle$ is either on the diagonal line $y=x$ or on the circle $C$ of radius $2$ centred at the origin. The product is negative if and only if $x^2+y^2-4$ and $x-y$ have opposite signs. That happens when either

- $x>y$ and $x^2+y^2-4<0$, or
- $x<y$ and $x^2+y^2-4>0$.

Points satisfying the first of these conditions are below the diagonal $y=x$ and inside $C$, and points satisfying the second are above the diagonal line and outside $C$.

Comment: +1: your words draw the necessary diagram very clearly in my mind's eye. @Tyler Dur: drawing a diagram is a good thing to do before trying to describe the diagram without drawing it!

Comment: Thanks, I just was courious if there is an algebraic solution to the problem w/o the argumentation using diagrams?

Comment: @Tyler: It really depends on what you mean by a solution. You’re talking about a region in the plane, so you can’t expect to get anything much nicer than a disjunction of cases: $x=y$, or $x^2+y^2=4$, or $x>y$ and $x^2+y^2<4$, or ... .